# Kolmogorov–Smirnov statistics as distance

Tags: python, kolmogorov-smirnov-test

I have a feature measured for each institution in each city. I want to calculate similarity between cities using the institutions' features. I think that if I compare the distributions pairwise and calculate the similarity of each pair of the cities distributions. Can I use Kolomogorov-Smirnov statistics for this purpose? Are the similarities of each pair comparable with each other? How do you incorporate the p-value in the analysis?

In general to obtain the ks statistics, I am using only one feature (float and can be positive or negative values) for each institution in a city, so in city1 I can have 10 institutions so I will have a float feature per institution, and in city2, I could have 200 institutions and each institution again will be represented by one float value. The values are also very small most of the time. So it's more like `ks.test(c(London_institution_1_float, ...,London_institution_10_float), c(Newyork_institution_1_float,...., Newyork_institution200_float))`

For example using the imaginary numbers below, which pairs do we consider the closest? Can we claim that  city3 is more similar to city1 than city2? Can we claim that city2 is more similar to city1 than city3?

- KS stats for (city1 , city1) = 0 , p=1
- KS stats for (city1, city2) = 0.001, p= .99
- KS stats for (city2, city3)= 0.9, p=.7
- KS stats for (city1, city3) = 0.5, p=.8

Comment: “Closer” in what sense? This seems like an XY problem where you have to solve problem X and propose method Y, so you ask about Y instead of X. Do you have an X?

Comment: @Dave, for the last part of my question, I am not asking what kind of similarity  KS stats measures, I am asking once we obtain the ks stat for a pair(regardless of whatever similarity it is measuring) is that comparable to the ks stat of another pair or is it meaningless beyond the pair itself. so is the ks stat valid for comparison across pairs?

Comment: The values that you plug into the KS test are measurements of cities on various parameters, right? As in `ks.test(c(LA_population, LA_crime_rate), c(London_population, London_crime_rate))`, right?

Comment: so for now I am using only one feature (float and can be positive or negative values) for each institution in a city, so in city1 I can have 10 institutions so I will have a float feature per institution, and in city2, I could have 200 institutions and each institution again will be represented by one float value. The values are also very small most of the time. So it's more like `ks.test(c(London_institution_1_float, ...,London_institution_10_float), c(Newyork_institution_1_float,...., Newyork_institution200_float))`

Comment: Okay so something more like `ks.test(c(LA_average income on 20th_street, LA_average_income_on_21st_street), c(London_average income on 20th_street, London_average_income_on_21st_street))`?

Comment: @Dave yes, I added an example in the comment above :) 

Answer (score 3):

The Kolmogorov-Smirnov test statistic is the maximum vertical
distance between the empirical CDFs (ECDFs) of the two samples
being compared.  I'm not sure whether this test statistic
compares the two samples in a way that is useful for your
purposes.

Consider the following three samples of size 100 (sampled in R):

```
set.seed(2022)
a = rgamma(100, 3, .2)
summary(a)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 1.447   9.405  13.271  14.018  18.790  32.065 

b = rgamma(100, 4, .25)
summary(b)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 1.936  10.618  15.105  16.464  21.279  38.398 

c = rgamma(100, 6, .3)
summary(c)
  Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
 4.164  14.351  19.578  20.334  26.404  45.439
```

Boxplots (bottom to top) of the three samples.

```
boxplot(a,b,c, horizontal=T, col="skyblue2", pch=20)
```

[image]

K-S tests distinguish between `b` and `c` and between `a` and `c`,
but not between `a` and `b`.

```
ks.test(a,b)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  a and b
D = 0.14, p-value = 0.281
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

ks.test(b,c)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  b and c
D = 0.23, p-value = 0.01008
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

ks.test(a,c)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  a and c
D = 0.34, p-value = 1.908e-05
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

ECDF plots are as follows:

```
hdr = "ECDF plots of Samples a (maroon), b (blue), and c"
plot(ecdf(c), col="green3", main=hdr)
 lines(ecdf(b), col="blue")
 lines(ecdf(a), col="maroon")
```

[image]

My three fictitious samples differ mainly in location, and
secondarily in dispersion. I'm not sure I would want to rely
on the maximum vertical distance in ECDF plots to distinguish
among them.

For such large samples, it may
be OK to use a Satterthwaite one-way test that does not
require equal variances. It finds significant differences,
and Welch two-sample t tests distinguish all three pairs,
at small P-values.

```
oneway.test(x ~ g)

        One-way analysis of means 
        (not assuming equal variances)

data:  x and g
F = 17.3, num df = 2.00, denom df = 196.47, p-value = 1.201e-07

t.test(a,b)$p.val
[1] 0.01919901
t.test(b,c)$p.val
[1] 0.0008458496
t.test(a,c)$p.val
[1] 1.706384e-08
```

By contrast, if the main differences among the samples
are in the shapes of the distributions from which they were
sampled, there may be situations in which K-S tests do what
you need.

Consider samples of size $n=100$ from exponential, normal, and
uniform distributions---all with means $1$ and SDs $1$.

```
set.seed(104)
A = rexp(100, 1)
B = rnorm(100, 1,1)
C = runif(100, 1-sqrt(3), 1+ sqrt(3))
```

[image]

Then
the K-S test can distinguish the exponential sample from the
other two. I suspect this is mainly because of the large difference in heights of the ECDFs at $0.$

```
ks.test(A,B)

       Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  A and B
D = 0.21, p-value = 0.02431
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

ks.test(B,C)

       Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  B and C
D = 0.12, p-value = 0.4676
alternative hypothesis: two-sided

ks.test(A,C)

        Two-sample Kolmogorov-Smirnov test

data:  A and C
D = 0.28, p-value = 0.0007873
alternative hypothesis: two-sided
```

I would not use an ANOVA to distinguish among these
three samples on account of the highly skewed exponential
sample. For whatever it's worth, a nonparametric Kruskal-Wallis test finds no
differences among these three samples. (The ECDF plot shows
that no sample dominates another.)

```
kruskal.test(X~G)

        Kruskal-Wallis rank sum test

data:  X by G
Kruskal-Wallis chi-squared = 1.069, df = 2, p-value = 0.586
```

[image]

The bottom line is that the K-S test works better in some settings
than in others. You need to decide whether the K-S test is useful for
distinguishing among *your* three samples.

Comment: very helpful answer . A question for you: How many institutions per city is big enough for the tests you are recommending? I have cities that may have 5 or so institutions,  should I remove those cities from my analysis using the tests you are suggesting?

Comment: I would hesitate to give exact numbers. Larger samples are usually better.  The K-S test and some nonparametric tests have especially poor power for small sample sizes.

Comment: For my purpose, as long as I know majority of the two distributions are behaving in a similar way(similar-ish overal shape, similar-ish mean, standard deviation and I would be Ok, if the distribution of a city has a very similar shape to another city but shifted I would want them to be dissimilar.